# Setting the RNG seed from the time

Tags: j

When you open up a new J console and execute:

```
? 1000
```

You'll always see the same result, 689 ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/B3tDAwOD/fwA)).

This is because the RNG will always start with the same initial seed.

I'm looking for a way to change the seed semi-randomly.  It doesn't have to be secure (eg, using milliseconds of time or some similar method is fine).

I assume I would do this using `9!:45` (documented on [this page](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d640.htm)) but I'm unsure how to proceed.

I also don't care which of the 4 RNGs I use.  I simply want a way to produce different random-ish results even in a fresh console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreign that you need to set the random seed is `9!:1` ([Random Seed](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm)).

You can use the `randomize` verb available from the `general/misc` addon to randomly set the random seed using `guids`, or current time if the `guid` script is not available. For example:

```
   9!:0 ''            NB. Query the random seed/link
16807
   require 'numeric'
   randomize ''       NB. Set a new seed for the session
_1672920848 1179844600 923541917 _282857428
   9!:0 ''            NB. Query the random seed/link
_1672920848 1179844600 923541917 _282857428
```

The definition of `randomize` is:

```
   randomize
3 : 0
 try.
   require 'guid'
   tmp=. _2 (3!:4) , guids 1
 catch.             NB. general/misc/guid.ijs not available
   tmp=. >:<.0.8*0 60 60 24 31#.0 0 0 0 _1+|.<.}.6!:0 ''
 end.
 ([ 9!:1) {.^:(2~:9!:42'') tmp    NB. set random initial random seed
)
```